# How logging models rows to see only model data?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 6 app when I log eloquent request like :

```
  $data= $this->orderBy('name')->get();
  \Log::info( ' $data::' . print_r( $data, true  ) );
```

I got array of complicated items with full structure of any model in resulting data.
If there is a way to show only data for any returned row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `toArray()`:

```
$data= $this->orderBy('name')->get()->toArray();
\Log::info( ' $data::' . json_encode( $data) );
```

And print array using `json_encode()`

Answer (score 1):

you can  use `toArray()` method.

```php
  $data= $this->orderBy('name')->get()->toArray();
```